# How to avoid that firebaseUI Email Link authentication opens a second browser tab?

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, password-less

When using the Email Link Authentication method with firebaseUI, the emailed hyperlink opens a new browser tab in order to confirm/authenticate the email reception to firebase, and then redirects to the initial URL. This leaves the user with two browser tabs with the same (authenticated) original URL.

Is there a way to end up with only one open browser tab?

I have tried to configure the firebaseUI EmailAuthProvider with an emailLinkSignIn function returning:

1. { url: '';}, this has no effect.
2. {url: '[another url]';}, this opens 'another url' but then does not authenticate the user in the original browser tab.

[firebaseUI-web - Configure Email Provider](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#configure-email-provider),
[firebaseUI-angular](https://github.com/RaphaelJenni/FirebaseUI-Angular)

Comment: I got an comment from the firebaseUI team on github that indicates there is no known way to do this. In other words (Firebase) Email/Link authentication will leave you with two instances of your app. https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/682 .